# Flutter: Elegant way to change text depending on context

Tags: flutter, text, provider

I want to be able to change flutter text elements depending on the current context.
For example the text might be `use 1 kg of flour` or `use 2 pounds of flour` depending on the user settings or locale.

The user's preference is made available using the `Provider` pattern, which is elegant to use.
However, in order to compute the final text though, I use Builders, e.g.:

```
String computeWeightString(double weightInKilograms, BuildContext context) => ... // compute text using Provider

Widget resultingText = Builder(builder: (context) => Text("use " + computeWeightString(1, context) + " of flour"));
```

This seems a bit cumbersome, and I'm sure the problem is quite common.
Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about "text changing by locale", it is actually `i18n` or `l10n`. You can see this official post: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: This is very good to know, thank you!
However, I'm not (only) interested in localization, but more in custom user configuration. This could be "what unit the user prefers", "how many decimal places the user prefers", "should text be verbose or not" - things like that. I think in those cases localization wouldn't work well.

Comment: @rgisi Maybe you can look at the l10n/i18n, and create your own code which is similar to that?